# Using TaskFalcon to schedule multiple projects for the same resources

Tags: planning, gantt

I'm currently using TaskFalcon (https://taskfalcon.org/) to schedule my projects, and I have this situation:

- I have a "low priority" project, where I want people to work 1d a week (weeklymax)
- I would like to have the same resources to work on other tasks for the rest of the week

Basically, I would like to assign 1d to "any task" of "project A" (low prio), and the remaining 4d to other tasks (depending on the schedule, etc.)
As far as I can see, this is not currently possible, because if I set the "weeklymax" field for all the tasks of "project A", the schedule will be: 1d for T1, 1d for T2, etc. ...leaving no room for other tasks.
I hope I explained my situation... if you need, I can provide an example as well.

What I tried: assigning a "weeklymax" to a group of tasks, saying "any task of this group should take 1d maximum", but this did not work (maybe "weeklymax" for the group is ignored?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned, if you limit the work on a task to 1 day per week, this restriction will only be applied to this task. So if you use this on multiple tasks on a sub-project, each task is only allowed to be worked on for one day per week, but a resource can work on a group of those tasks basically full time - just not more than one day on each individual task.

Technically, you could introduce artificial task dependencies to prevent multiple of those tasks to be in progress at the same time, but I would not recommend this as long as it doesn't reflect "real task dependencies", since this might make things more complicated if multiple resources become involved.

With a filter, you can use similar limits for a resource instead of a task, which allows you to apply restrictions on all the tasks a given resource works on.

Unfortunately, in the current version 0.9.19 of TaskFalcon, `filters` don't support the `weeklymax` parameter, but you can use `workingtime` to achieve a similar result.

```
resources:
  - resource: W1
    name: Worker

  - filter: one-day-per-week 
    workingtime: MON             # The filter allows a resource to only work on Mondays

tasks:
  - task: T1
    efforts: 2d 4h
    assign: W1.one-day-per-week  # Assigns the resource with the configured restrictions for this task
```

The difference between `weeklymax: 8h` and `workingtime: MON` is, that you can not tell the resource to work on a task any time during a week but in total not more than 8 hours. Instead you tell the resource that it is allowed to work on a task full time, but only on a specific day.

Here is a full example:

```
project:
  name: Limited project time per week
  start: 2020-06-01

resources:
  - resource: W1
    name: Worker

  - filter: one-day-per-week 
    workingtime: MON

tasks:
  - group: P1
    name: Project A (One day per week)
    priority: 100

    tasks:
      - task: T1
        name: First task
        efforts: 2d 4h
        assign: W1.one-day-per-week 

      - task: T2
        name: Second task
        efforts: 1d 4h
        assign: W1.one-day-per-week

  - group: P2
    name: Project B (Rest of available time)
    priority: 90

    tasks:
      - task: First task
        efforts: 6d
        assign: W1

      - task: Second task
        efforts: 6d
        assign: W1
```

[image: Example]

Since the one day limit is not applied to the tasks directly, but to the resource, all tasks where the resource filter is used, now share the same limitations.

The priority of a task is also important here.
You've mentioned that `Project A` is a low priority project because you can only work on it one day each week. The above example uses a different understanding of what priority means, since here it is a high priority project with a working restriction of one-day-per-week.
You could also address this from a different angle and create a 4-days-per-week limit for `Project B` and work the rest of the time on `Project A`. In this case `Project B` would need to have a higher priority, so `Project A` would be allocated resources only if the constraints for `Project B` are already satisfied.

The main difference between those two approaches would be if for some reason you would have less time in a given week to decide where this time gets taken away. Let's assume you need to work on an even higher prioritised task for a third project for another day per week.
In the provided example, you would still be able to work on `Project A` for one day per week and one day less for `Project B`, since `Project A` has a higher priority.
If `Project B` was higher in priority, with a 4-days-per-week limit, then you wouldn't be able to work on `Project A` anymore, since `Project B` would get all of the remaining 4 days in this week.